# How can I bend skirting for a bay window?

Tags: wood

We have a bay window in our living room with a fast approaching deadline for the carpet being fitted. We need to bend the skirting as it won't be as pleasing to the eye if we do it in chunks and our bay is curved.

Can anyone please advise on how to do this as our joiner can't come out to help any time soon.

Answer (score 2):

So, more of a bow window than a bay window, per the usual terminology where the smooth curve is a bow.

The typical approach is to kerf the back of the piece you need to bend. Depending on the profile, this can be simple or more difficult - the basic concept is to make a cut every 1/2 inch or centimeter (approximately - don't get fussy about measuring them!) that leaves only 1/8-1/4" of wood on the face intact, at which point the board should bend into place easily. If there is a molded profile on the face of the board, this becomes trickier, since you need to be careful not to cut through the board where the molded profile is deep.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Resin-based flexible molding. Something like http://www.flextrim.com/index.php

Standard profiles are available, so you have a good chance of matching one of their products to your existing skirting.

Answer (score 0):

I have used PVC that is available in the standard 1X sizes in the big box stores. Top caps are available in PVC too, but those are tricky to set in place. The 1X PVC can be machined to a profile with the same tools for wood if you need to match something.